# AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5403 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.)

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have created login page, in that login page I have used get x package. In login page I am creating text form field using form widget and have assigned global key to it -> var formKey = GlobalKey();

then I copied code of login page to create register page but it is showing this error

AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5403 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.)

```html
import 'package:book_store/user/sign_up.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/get_state_manager.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordController = TextEditingController();
  var isObsecure = true.obs;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: "my app",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (context, dataSnapShot) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, cons) {
              return ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: cons.maxHeight,
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 285,
                      child: Image.asset("lib/assets/book_books_bookshelf.jpg"),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white24,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                blurRadius: 8,
                                color: Colors.black26,
                                offset: Offset(0, -3),
                              ),
                            ]),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 20, 30, 20),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(height: 20),
                              // for email
                              Form(
                                key: formKey,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    TextFormField(
                                      controller: emailController,
                                      // if user put form empty
                                      validator: (val) => val == ""
                                          ? "please write email"
                                          : null,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                          Icons.email,
                                          color: Colors.amber,
                                        ),
                                        hintText: "abc@gmail.com",
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.white70,
                                            )),
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.white70,
                                            )),
                                        disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.white70,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                              color: Colors.white70,
                                            )),
                                        contentPadding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 3.0,
                                          vertical: 8.0,
                                        ),
                                        fillColor: Colors.white38,
                                        filled: true,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 30,
                                    ),
                                    //----------------password---------------------------------------------------
                                    Obx(() => TextFormField(
                                          controller: passwordController,
                                          obscureText: isObsecure.value,
                                          // if user put form empty
                                          validator: (val) => val == ""
                                              ? "please write password"
                                              : null,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                              Icons.key,
                                              color: Colors.amber,
                                            ),
                                            suffixIcon:
                                                Obx(() => GestureDetector(
                                                      onTap: () => {
                                                        isObsecure.value =
                                                            !isObsecure.value,
                                                      },
                                                      child: Icon(
                                                        isObsecure.value
                                                            ? Icons
                                                                .visibility_off
                                                            : Icons.visibility,
                                                      ),
                                                    )),
                                            hintText: "password",
                                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.white70,
                                                )),
                                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.white70,
                                                )),
                                            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.white70,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.white70,
                                                )),
                                            contentPadding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 3.0,
                                              vertical: 8.0,
                                            ),
                                            fillColor: Colors.white38,
                                            filled: true,
                                          ),
                                        )),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 30,
                                    ),
                                    //---------------material-------------------------------------------
                                    Material(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38),
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {},
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38),
                                        child: const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: 10,
                                            horizontal: 10,
                                          ),
                                          child: Text(
                                            "login",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  const Text("Don't have an Account?"),
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Get.to(SignUp());
                                      },
                                      child: const Text("Register here"))
                                ],
                              ),
                              const Text(
                                "Or",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                              //----------------admin text ---------------------------
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  const Text("Are you an admin?"),
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      child: const Text("click here"))
                                ],
                              ),
                              // SizedBox(height: 10,)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
              );
            }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my login page

```html
import 'package:book_store/user/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_navigation/src/root/get_material_app.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // using get dependency so that state can be easily managed
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'book store app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch:  Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (context, dataSnapShot){
          return Login();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my main.dart page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you say you copy the LoginPage for the SignUpPage.

If you copy the whole code, you will end up having two GetMaterialApp in your widget tree when you tap to navigate to SignUp page.

The error indicate that it should be only one GetMaterialApp in the widget tree, also GetX also document that you can change the MaterialApp with GetMaterialApp if you using GetX Navigate, show dialog, etc

main.dart

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // using get dependency so that state can be easily managed
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'book store app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        builder: (context, dataSnapShot) {
          return Login();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

sign_up.dart

```
class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Semantics(
      value: "Sign Up Page",
    );
  }
}
```

login.dart

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordController = TextEditingController();
  var isObsecure = true.obs;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, cons) {
        return ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: cons.maxHeight,
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white24,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          color: Colors.black26,
                          offset: Offset(0, -3),
                        ),
                      ]),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 20, 30, 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        // for email
                        Form(
                          key: formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: emailController,
                                // if user put form empty
                                validator: (val) =>
                                    val == "" ? "please write email" : null,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.email,
                                    color: Colors.amber,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "abc@gmail.com",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.white70,
                                      )),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.white70,
                                      )),
                                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white70,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.white70,
                                      )),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 3.0,
                                    vertical: 8.0,
                                  ),
                                  fillColor: Colors.white38,
                                  filled: true,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 30,
                              ),
                              //----------------password---------------------------------------------------
                              Obx(() => TextFormField(
                                    controller: passwordController,
                                    obscureText: isObsecure.value,
                                    // if user put form empty
                                    validator: (val) => val == ""
                                        ? "please write password"
                                        : null,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.key,
                                        color: Colors.amber,
                                      ),
                                      suffixIcon: Obx(() => GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () => {
                                              isObsecure.value =
                                                  !isObsecure.value,
                                            },
                                            child: Icon(
                                              isObsecure.value
                                                  ? Icons.visibility_off
                                                  : Icons.visibility,
                                            ),
                                          )),
                                      hintText: "password",
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.white70,
                                          )),
                                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.white70,
                                          )),
                                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white70,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.white70,
                                          )),
                                      contentPadding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 3.0,
                                        vertical: 8.0,
                                      ),
                                      fillColor: Colors.white38,
                                      filled: true,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 30,
                              ),
                              //---------------material-------------------------------------------
                              Material(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38),
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38),
                                  child: const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10,
                                      horizontal: 10,
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "login",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const Text("Don't have an Account?"),
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Get.to(SignUp());
                                },
                                child: const Text("Register here"))
                          ],
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          "Or",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        //----------------admin text ---------------------------
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            const Text("Are you an admin?"),
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: const Text("click here"))
                          ],
                        ),
                        // SizedBox(height: 10,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Navigate to SignUp

```
Get.to(const SignUp())
```